# A managed resource modules "aws" has not been declared in the root module in terraform

Tags: module, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Here is my tree command execute in terminal
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDVyG.png)

When i execute terraform plan i got below error and my issue i want to deploy a new VM in Azure/GCP/AWS using terraform only one file i.e., only i need to change just resource type, machine type, resource name and others in terraform files which is going to deploy in Azure/GCP/AWS. So for i got below terraform file to used it but got error dont know will all this files will work or not in Azure/GCP/AWS.

Im new to terraform struck below error from many hours search google didnt understand where i can learn more on modules

Here is my error

```
│ Error: Reference to undeclared resource
│
│   on output.tf line 5, in output "aws_ip":
│    5:   value = aws_instance.vm_instance.public_ip
│
│ A managed resource "aws_instance" "vm_instance" has not been declared in the root module.
╵
╷
│ Error: Reference to undeclared resource
│
│   on output.tf line 10, in output "aws_ssh_connection_string":
│   10:   value = modules.aws.ssh_connection_string
│
│ A managed resource "modules" "aws" has not been declared in the root module.
```

Here is my output.tf file

```
### AWS Outputs ###
output "aws_ip" {
  description = "The public IP address of the AWS virtual machine"
#  value = modules.aws.ip
  value = aws_instance.vm_instance.public_ip
}

output "aws_ssh_connection_string" {
  description = "The SSH command to connect to the AWS virtual machine"
  value = modules.aws.ssh_connection_string
}
```

Here is my main.tf file

```
module "AWS" {
  aws_region = var.aws_region
  aws_creds_file = var.aws_creds_file
  aws_profile = var.aws_profile
  ssh_pub_key_file = var.ssh_pub_key_file
  ssh_priv_key_file = var.ssh_priv_key_file
  aws_instance = var.vm_instance.public_ip
  source = "./modules/aws/"
#  source = "./home/osboxes/Documents/Terraform-All-VMs/Onetime-Deploy/modules/aws"
}

#module "Azure" {
#  azure_location = var.azure_location
#  ssh_user = var.ssh_user
#  ssh_pub_key_file = var.ssh_pub_key_file
#  ssh_priv_key_file = var.ssh_priv_key_file
#  source = "./modules/azure"
#}
```

Here is my variable.tf

```
 ### AWS Specific Variables ###
variable "aws_region" {
  description = "The AWS region to deploy the resources to"
}

variable "aws_creds_file" {
  description = "The full path to the .aws/credentials file"
}

variable "aws_profile" {
  description = "The profile in the credentials tile to use"
}

### Azure Specific Variables ###
#variable "azure_location" {
#  description = "The region of Azure resource group for this HitC Exercise"
#  type = string
#}

### GCP Specific Variables ###
#variable "gcp_project" {
#  description = "The GCP Project ID to deploy the VM"
#}

#variable "gcp_region" {
#  description = "The GCP Region to deploy the VM"
#}

#variable "gcp_zone" {
#  description = "The GCP Zone to deploy the VM"
#}

#variable "gcp_key_file" {
#  description = "The path to the GCP Service Account"
#}

### Common Variables ###
variable "ssh_user" {
  description = "The local user account to create on the virtual machine"
  type = string
}

variable "ssh_pub_key_file" {
  description = "The path to the public SSH key associated with the local user account"
  type = string
}

variable "ssh_priv_key_file" {
  description = "The path to the private SSH key associated with the local user account"
  type = string
}
```

Here is my modules/aws/output.tf files

```
output "ip" {
  description = "The public IP address of the virtual machine"
  value = aws_instance.vm_instance.public_ip
}

output "ssh_connection_string" {
  description = "The SSH command to connect to the virtual machine"
  value = "ssh -i ${var.ssh_priv_key_file} ubuntu@${aws_instance.vm_instance.public_ip}"
}
```

i try to add some value = modules.aws.ip but couldnt understand how to add or change when comes to modules in output or in different files

as i said i want to deploy in aws/gcp/azure any one cloud at a time using above files, if files are not correct plse suggest to me how to write good output.tf and main.tf and variables.tf many more

please as im new in terraform

If u need any other file do let me will share it

Comment: Are there any outputs defined in the AWS module? If so, please add that to the question.

Comment: yes and i have added it

Comment: Ok, so the original try was very close, but you have to take care about capitalization. The output `value = modules.aws.ip` is not the same as `value = modules.AWS.ip`. The latter should work based on your code.

Comment: after changing to value = modules.AWS.ip in output.tf still im getting same error do also i need to change in other files apart from output.tf

Comment: If you are going to reference **any** output that gets created with the module named `"AWS"`, you have to use that name everywhere, i.e., `module.AWS.<output name>`, where the `<output name>` is the name of the output you have defined inside of the module code.

Comment: thanks for but still im not able to understand as i told im new to terraform can u just tell me exact file name where that i need to change

Comment: You need to change the `output.tf` in the root of the project.

Comment: after changing in root of output.tf  output "aws_ip" to output "AWS_ip" and value = modules.AWS_ip got same error

Comment: I didn't write that, I wrote value = module.AWS.ip. You don't have to change anything in modules/aws/output.tf. Only the output.tf in the root of the project.

Comment: i did like u say but again it throw same error and i dint change in modules/aws/output.tf anything but change in output.tf that was module.AWS.ip if im wrong then plse u tell me what exact line should i do change

Answer (score 0):

If you are intending to refer to your `module "AWS"` block then the correct reference syntax would be `module.AWS`.

Terraform thinks that `modules.aws` is referring to a resource of type "modules" with the name "aws", because a resource type is the default interpretation of any top-level symbol that isn't a reserved word. The singular `module` is the reserved word for referring to module calls, and the attributes of that pseudo-object are case-sensitive.

Comment: $terraform plan

│ Error: Reference to undeclared module
│   on output.tf line 4, in output "aws_ip":
│    4:   value = module.AWS_ip
│ No module call named "AWS_ip" is declared in the root module.
╵
$ cat output.tf
### AWS Outputs ###
output "aws_ip" {
  description = "The public IP address of the AWS virtual machine"
  value = module.AWS_ip
}

as you can see in output.tf i made changes after that still throw error even i change to capital letter in output "AWS_ip" { still it throw error

Comment: That's a different error, and I can't read it because it's all crammed into a comment. Please either edit your question to describe what you tried and share that error in full as part of the question, or start a new question about this new problem.